# Docker Desktop Kubernetes - node performance and allocation limits

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running kubernetes on docker desktop kubernetes where I have 2 namespaces for my dev and staging environments (prod is managed by cloud provider).

Sometimes I notice the performance of the cluster is not the best and I get timeouts.

I am running this on a Mac Studio with 124 GB memory and 20 core CPUs, out of which I allocated docker the following amounts [image]

The problem is that the Node recognised by kubernetes has some limits set in the following way: [image]

The node's yaml config file states these details [image]

I would expect that the limits would reflect the settings, or am I not understanding them correctly?

I tried updating manually the node config yaml but no success. Every update gets reverted.

Tried scaling the resources but I want more performance so scaling down does not really help.